# Profile lookup on freecode camp checkpoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I'm going through freecodecamp and I'm solving the problems there, to keep in the loop with the programming and I've stumbled on a snag, and I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

So I have an array of objects called contacts, and I need to create a function called `lookUp(firstName, prop)`. The text of the assignment is like this:

> The function should check if `firstName` is an actual contact's `firstName` and the given property (`prop`) is a property of that contact.
>
> If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
>
> If `firstName` does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"
>
> If `prop` does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No such property"

The code:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intruiging Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    },
];


function lookUp( firstName, prop ){
  for( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++ ){
    if( contacts[i].firstName == firstName ) {
      if( contacts[i].hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        return contacts[i].prop;
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    } else {
      return "No such contact";
    } 
  }
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUp("Kristian", "lastName");
```

So I'm looping through the array with `for` loop checking each object. In the first `if` I check if the `firstName` property of that objects equals the function parameter firstName, then if it's true, I check if the object has the property `prop`, and I should be able to return it. But it seems that

```
return contacts[i].prop;
```

is not working, and I'm kinda lost as to why. I'm sure it's something trivial, but I don't see why. When I go to console, and test

```
contacts[0].likes
```

I get out the array `["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]`, but in my if that's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Ok so I tried with

```
function lookUp( firstName, prop ){
  for( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++ ){
    if( contacts[i].firstName == firstName ) {
      if( contacts[i].hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    } else {
      return "No such contact";
    } 
  }
}
```

But I still get the same error :\

Comment: No, it's totally unrelated to the 'duplicate' in question, I returned too early :)

Comment: And the question was asked 2 years ago...

Comment: Yeah, actually, > 2.5 years ago, which makes this conversation not that useful. Mostly I saw that the question was being voted to be closed as a typo. I prefer to have things closed as duplicates, when possible, to be signposts. In this case, I was too eager to make that happen. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, not a problem, not sure why so many close votes all of a sudden :D I'm fine the post being closed or opened as long as it helps :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I'm dumb, I exited my for loop too early:

```
function lookUp( firstName, prop ){
  for( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++ ){
    if( firstName == contacts[i].firstName ) {
      if( contacts[i].hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}
```

This works.

Comment: Ow, haha see you figured it out on your own. Don't feel dumb, we all make mistakes.

Comment: thanks - this helped me figure out i needed to use `return contacts[i][prop]` and not `return contacts[i].prop` lol i wish that was explained better in the checkpoint.

Comment: @Jeannie I think you are confused because `prop` is a variable in this function. I have made you a fiddle to show the different ways to access a value: https://jsfiddle.net/mgqwj9g1/2/. Keep practicing it will become clearer in the future.

Comment: @Mikey wow ok yes i think this will only become more clear with practice. thank you for laying each out separately. that definitely helps.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused about what return does. Your code will only do one iteration and `return "No such contact"`. Return immediately stops the function to execute. Here is a fiddle of what I mean demonstrated with `console.log` https://jsfiddle.net/oegw3a4y/

In your situation, the first iteration evaluates to false in the first `if` statement and immediately goes to the `else`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function lookUp(firstName, prop){
  var ans="";
  for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){

//if firstname matches,fetch the property
if(contacts[i].firstName==firstName)
  {
    //in the item matched with first name check if the property is there or not.
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
       ans=contacts[i][prop];
    }
    else{
      ans="No such property";
    }

  }
  }

  // if no contact found after searching entire collection.then ans will be empty
  if(ans==="") ans="No such contact";  
  return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return call needs to be the last thing in the stack. The above won't work because the function returns "No such contact" before the loop can iterate to the next increment! The following works:

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for ( var i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
      if ( contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === true) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
        } 
        return "No such property";

    }    
  }
  return "No such contact";
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: Jup, I know you can check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34798415/629127) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
   for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
       if((contacts[i].firstName===firstName)&&
         (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)===true)){
             return contacts[i][prop];
       }else if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)===false){
          return "No such property" ;
       } 
   }
       return "No such contact" ;
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to the corrected code. This improves the quality of the answer and is more understandable for others that may have a similar issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  if (firstName === contacts[i].firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    return contacts[i][prop];
  }
}

for (var j = 0; j < contacts.length; j++) {
  if (firstName === contacts[j].firstName && contacts[j].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
    return 'No such property';
  }
}
    return 'No such contact';
// Only change code above this line
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, what it does etc.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I did just using the tools we have been given so far in FCC.

```
var o = "";

function lookUp(firstName, prop) {
for (i = 0; i <= contacts.length - 1; i++) {
       if (firstName === contacts[i].firstName && (contacts[i][prop])) {
           return (contacts[i][prop]);
   }
   }
// if property look up returns undefined type then there is no such property
        if ((contacts[0][prop]) === undefined) {
         o = "No such property";
     } else {
         o = "No such contact";
     }   
    return o;   
}
```